# Provide application settings to user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have Android application that does Google autentication with Firebase. I need this in order to provide application user some settings. I suppose these settings should be stored in database and I can get them by making selection with provided user_id.

After authentication I was provided with some user info. I suppose I should use Token as user_id. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
{idpResponse=IdpResponse{mUser=User{mProviderId='google.com', mEmail='xxx@gmail.com', mPhoneNumber='null', mName='Dalai Lama', mPhotoUri=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACxxxiVN_hQM13VOGy7Z18i26bHMDlCytH=s96-c}, mToken=
'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQ4YTYzYmM0NzY3Zjg1NTBhNTMyZGM2MzBjZjdlYjQ5ZmYzOTdlN2MiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.YlaKj_MRNZFzLsDl1tuCseHhcc4xxHFpL91ICCCLAAn-Nx4ns3NaYbmNpPXLZ3_Ei2iHcN3ZdrfkWLQBaxvERMFUwLyP9t3NjUI7phKqEg0xy3XJFfoj5EEDHLTsc3336MHRFhbCpp3KWfhSDZXUSGqTFlAgK6-lHTHt2AbP_HD2ynCjsGCPDmAUf4hExPNq0znF-gdZCnbJvPhwIC4yYP12YWpLhpYxZtHl7F13RqlQ3XKqdrHwwp238bZH2R-0Km1oI7fbL85BbWOvaUNIbC1k4hBmrRBpvFsAsZmNApODLikdkMbHeThWlrgGPCyDtqCi8zSoOdp2Y-pKGw7FzA', mSecret='null', mIsNewUser='false', mException=null, mPendingCredential=null}, resultCode='-1}
```

What is the simplest way to implement settings for an application with authenticated users? Can I user Firebase for this purpose?